# How can I delete a tag from Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

So, I am writing some code against Google Reader's "API".

I am writing code that deletes all of the sites in a folder/tag. I can delete the sites just fine, but I can't find a way to delete the tag when everything is out of it.

So in the end all the sites are gone but I have this empty tag.

I am currently trying this, but google doesn't like it.

http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?client=XXX

POST params = "r=user/-/label/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(label) + "&T=" + Token

It seems to want a feed to go with it, but the point here isn't to remove a label from a feed (I can do that just fine), it is to remove the tag completely.

Any thoughts?

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete tags by sending a POST request to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/disable-tag with the parameters `s` (tag to delete, i.e. `user/-/label/tag_name`) and `T` (the action token).